# What disk (and how) Windows will use after a soft/hard link is created?

Tags: ssd

I believe there is no better place to ask than here at stack. Assuming we have 2 SSD and first  we create a soft link in Windows Disk 1 in partition C:\ for example like `C:\Program Files\folder_from_drive_d` linked.

> While in driver D:\ (disk 2) is the original folder.

Everytime I execute/read/write a file, program or game inside that folder in Disk 1. Which storage will be used? Is it a 100% usage of that disk or 50%/50%,

A. Both disks will be used.
B. Only disk 1 will be used.
C. Only disk 2 will be used.

> XYZ problem: The issue of this question addresses the usability and concerns over time with the lifespan of SSDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the above. It's more like 0.01% of `C:` (the disk containing the link) and 99.99% of `D:` (the disk that is the target of the link).

Disk `C:` will generally not be used because the data of the linked files is not **on** disk `C:`. (I mean, that's the *whole point of a symbolic link,* isn't it.)

The only data being read from `C:` is the existence and "target path" of the symlink itself, as well as the existence of its parent directories (all of which will be cached in memory for some time); any file operations on paths that *cross* the link will be redirected to its target path at `D:\`.

Hardlinks cannot be created across filesystems.